# how can i open pdf as bytes by pypdfium2 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, byte

i have a database and i store the pdf files as bytes in LONGBLOB cell , after that i want to get the PDF file from the Database as bytes and open it directly using pypdfium2.

but i did not find any way to do it by myself, for that i need your helps.

i user this method to open the PDF file from a path in my computer :

```py
import pypdfium2

file_path = "mm.pdf"

open_the_pdf_file = pypdfium2.PdfDocument(file_path)
determine_the_page = open_the_pdf_file.get_page(0)
```

is there any possibility to do it ?

thanks.

Comment: From the documentation ( https://pypi.org/project/pypdfium2/ ) - you can just pass binary data as input. 
"class PdfDocument supports file path strings, bytes, and byte buffers"

Comment: thank you very much i did not think about that.
it works.

if you wrote it like an answer i will accept it.